# Are there infinitely many $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(n+1)$ which are both 3-smooth numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

$\phi(323)=288$ and $\phi(324)=108$.

$108$ and $288$ are 3-smooth numbers, that is product of 2's and 3's.

So I wonder if there are infinitely many integers n such that:

$\phi(n)$ and $\phi(n+1)$ are both 3-smooth numbers.

Comment: For $n$ to satisfy this, you need both $n$ and $n+1$ to be a product of a $3$-smooth number and distinct [Pierpont primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierpont_prime). Given we don't know if there are infinitely many of the latter, I doubt the answer to your question is known.

Comment: @Wojowu: good point! Moreover, it seems that infinitness of the numbers in question would imply infinitness of Pierpont primes.